# df output problem - want free space not inodes

Tags: linux, disk-usage

I have been unable to get disk usage from df. Instead I am getting Free inodes regardless of asking for block sizes using -BM or other sizes.

My computer harddisk is /dev/sda which has 3 partitions with the following partitions and disk usage using lsblk:

```
[matta@matta]: ~>$ lsblk /dev/sda -o NAME,SIZE,TYPE,FSUSED,FSUSE%
NAME     SIZE TYPE FSUSED FSUSE%
sda    119.2G disk        
├─sda1   212M part 141.9M    71%
├─sda2   118G part  73.1G    63%
└─sda3     1G part
```

If I type df:

```
[matta@matta]: ~>$ df /dev/sda
Filesystem     Type Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      ext4   7.4M  1.3M  6.2M   17% /
total          -      7.4M  1.3M  6.2M   17% -
```

or df -BM:

```
[matta@matta]: ~>$ df -BM /dev/sda2
Filesystem     Type  Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      ext4 7741440 1270517 6470923   17% /
total          -    7741440 1270517 6470923   17% -
```

I want the output to show free disk space, not free inodes.

Comment: Is `df` aliased to `df -Ti --total`? What's the output of `type df`?

Comment: it looks like you got it... `df is aliased to "df -ahiT --total"` Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
[matta@matta]: ~>$ type df
df is aliased to `df -ahiT --total'
```

to unalias it: `unalias df`

and now...

```
[matta@matta]: ~>$ df -BG /dev/sda2
Filesystem     1G-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2           116G   74G       37G  67% /
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `df` is alias-ed. You can avoid using the alias without unalias-ing it by using a `\` before the command. So, try,

```
\df /dev/sda
```

Otherwise try:

```
unalias df
df /dev/sda
```